# Devexpress xtrareport has issues with version 1607 update of windows 10

Tags: .net, wpf, devexpress, xtrareport

Last week I did a windows 10 update to version 1607. This update also installed .NET Framework 4.6.2.

In our WPF application we use devexpress XtraReports v13.2.

At runtime the software now crashes when we try to show the report (LoadLayout step)

I get this exception:

> The type 'System.Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

There is a similar inner exception comming from devexpress:

> Inner Exception 1: Type:
>   DevExpress.XtraReports.Serialization.XRSerializationException Message:
>   0:  The type 'System.Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

This all work fine before the update. Any Ideas what could cause this?

Comment: What is the target framework of your projects??

Comment: .NET Framework 4.6

Comment: Version 13.2 supports both .net 4 and .net 4.5 frameworks. If you want to use higher version then you must upgrade DevExpress controls to higher then 14 or higher..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reacted on a ticket on the devexpress site (the issue also occurred in later versions, it only happens when a touch screen is attached)
They've provided a fix. 
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T431199

Answer (score 0):

> Last week I did a Windows 10 update to version 1607. This update also
>   installed .NET Framework 4.6.2.
>   In our WPF application we use DevExpress XtraReports v13.2.

Take a look at the [DevExpress WinForms Controls system requirements page](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument8092) -
there is no official support for .NET 4.6 version in v 13.2.

Thus you should upgrade your XtraRepors at least to 14.2 version.

Comment: Installed the trial version of v 14.2. This still has the same issue

Comment: If so, the better solution is to contact DevExpress support [directly](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create).

Answer (score 0):

On this ticket https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T431199/serialization-xrserializationexception-is-thrown-on-an-attempt-to-load-a-report-when-a

[image]

Additional information work for me .

1. Download the WinMDFix.cs file and add in to your project.
2. Add this on application startup event WinMDFix.Helper.Replace();

   public partial class App : Application
               {
                   private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
                   {
                       WinMDFix.Helper.Replace();
                   }
               }